# How do I run cx_Oracle queries within my session limit?

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I am querying an Oracle database through cx_Oracle Python and getting the following error after 12 queries. How can I run multiple queries within the same session? Or do I need to quit the session after each query? If so, how do I do that?

> DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-02391: exceeded
> simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit
>  (Background on this error at:
> https://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)

My code looks something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
```

```
def get_query(item):
    ...
    return valid_query

cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r"\instantclient_21_3")
user = ...
password = ...
tz = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(...,
                            ...,
                            service_name=...)
cstr = f'oracle://{user}:{password}@{dsn_tns}'
engine = create_engine(cstr,
                       convert_unicode=False,
                       pool_recycle=10,
                       pool_size=50,
                       echo=False)
df_dicts = {}
for item in items:
    df = pd.read_sql_query(get_query(item), con=cstr)
    df_dicts[item.attribute] = df
```

Thank you!

Comment: Seems `read_sql_query` creates a new engine when using `con=cstr` . Wonder it close the created session.

Will your program work if you use `con=engine`?

Comment: `ORA-02391` is a database limitation.  The problem could be your code's use of connections, or the SQL statements use of parallelism.  In Python if your queries are executed sequentially, then either reuse the same connection instead of opening new connections, or make sure to close the old connections before opening a new one.  It's better to reuse a connection.  If the problem is the SQL, then you will have to review it with the DBA or a SQL expert.  Also check if other people are using the DB with the same username.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cx_Oracle connection object directly in Pandas - for Oracle connection I always found that worked better than sqlalchemy for simple use as a Pandas connection.

Something like:

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(f'{user}/{password}@{dsn_tns}')
df_dicts = {}
for item in items:
    df = pd.read_sql(sql=get_query(item), con=conn, parse_dates=True)
    df_dicts[item.attribute] = df
```

(Not sure if you had dates, I just remember that being a necessary element for parsing).

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and it seemed to have worked but then it raised the same error, this time after 326 iterations/queries. Any ideas why that might be?